# Extjs 4.0.2a breaks grid column hiding?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have just updated my program to use Ext JS 4.0.2a, from the previous 4.0.0. Some parts of my program break after the upgrade, and one of them is that the show/hide column option for the grid doesn't display correctly. The screenshot below is how things render on my machine;

[image: Option not showing correctly]

Notice that the column list renders on top of the page, and the list itself is empty.

I'm not sure if this is platform/browser specific, but I'm using Ubuntu Linux, and I get such error when running my program in Firefox and also Chromium.

The following is how my grid column is declared:

```
{
      xtype: 'gridcolumn',
      header: 'windspeed_max',
      sortable: true,
      width: 105,
      dataIndex: 'windspeed_max'
},
```

I did not include the 'hideable' option, as it defaults to true anyway, yet the problem still persist even after adding the 'hideable' option and set it to true. I'm not sure if this option has anything to do with the problem anyway.

The question is, how can I fix this problem, without falling back to Ext JS 4.0.0?

Comment: check if you using correct css

Comment: The page only load 1 CSS file, and that file is "resources/css/ext-all.css" in the Ext JS directory. Is there any other CSS file that I need to load?

Comment: check if you've copied all new images and other resources into project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, fix is to do the following as explained at: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?138927-4.0.2a-Large-Ext.menu.Menu-incorrectly-shown-(Possible-fix)&p=620730&viewfull=1#post620730

I tested using Ext 4.0.2a version, and works..

In the Ext.menu.Menu.doConstrain function... 
change:

```
...
delete me.height;
me.setSize();
full = me.getHeight();
...
```

To:

```
...
full = me.getHeight();
delete me.height;
me.setSize();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The menu constraining has been fixed since 4.0.2a. When the next public release comes out (very soon) the fix will be in there.

Answer (score 0):

The bug menu from Ext JS 4.0.2a is fixed in the new available version [Ext JS 4.0.7](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/download/)